# How to extend default setting in 30 seconds of waiting in Selenium to waiting until success

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, timeoutexception

I have a JMeter Webdriver script which works correctly during all scenario steps.
But in case of slowly getting response after changes on page making by script, sometimes following error happens:

```
Response code:500
Response message:javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for element to be clickable: By.xpath: //<some_xpath>] (tried for 30 second(s) with 500 milliseconds interval)
```

The issue connected specifically with selenium settings to wait only 30 seconds and not more in the context of slowly working functionality on the page (which needed sometimes more time for page changes than 30 sec).

If the step of Selenium script could take sometimes >30 seconds (due to possible slow response), how is it possible to switch off default 30 sec limit and wait **until success**?
I do not need to see error after only 30 seconds, I need to wait until it goes to the next step in script - whatever time it takes. So, I don't want to have any limit at all to prevent scenario interruption in the middle, I'm ready to wait whatever it will take.

I didn't set any limits by my own:

```
driver = vars.getObject("driver");
wait = vars.getObject("wait");
```

Could you please advice, what is the best way to switch off this 30 sec default limit?

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE). Take the code you are using, reduce it to an MCVE, and then post that code, properly formatted. Post the full error message as text, properly formatted, and indicate on which line the error is occurring. Post the relevant HTML as text, also properly formatted.

Comment: You can increase your wait period.... but you don't want that to be infinite because it may never succeed.

Comment: @JeffC, the MCVE code is shared - no specific limits in 30 sec were set up. Piece of code doing specific scenario on page is not relevant to my question, the Q is in long page responding >30s - my script works OK when waiting for changed content <30 sec, but when page content is changing longer than 30 sec, then the provided in topic error occurring due to 30 sec limit of waiting (interruption is not acceptable for my goal). The question is if I didn't set limitation in 30 sec but it applied somehow, what is option to switch off this 30 sec limit at all, to continue scenario on very slow page.

Comment: @Shawn, the question is not about my scenario code. Scenario code works correct. Please see the description - I updated it with more details.

Comment: @pcalkins, infinite is not possible technically - due to server timeout which is natural limit of waiting and the best match in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [WebDriver.Timeouts](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api/latest/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.Timeouts.html)

Example usage:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(java.time.Duration.of(5, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES))
```

Alternatively you can use WebDriver [Waits](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/)

More information on Groovy scirpting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. I like you idea to extend waiting in JMeter Webdriver script until natural server timeout.